# How can I synchronize php or client time with MySQL time?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, cakephp

On my server there is a difference between the database server time and the php time, and I need them synced for my (CakePHP) app. I have a log in the database with timestamp and I need to display a jQuery counter from that moment on. When I leave it as default, it starts from 1:03:58 instead of 0:00:00. What is the way to do this?

This is the counter code, the php $counter variable contains the database timestamp int value.

```
$('#counter').countdown({since: <?php echo $counter?>, format: 'HMS', compact: true});
```

This is the jquery plugin I am using for the counter:
http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html

This is where $counter gets the value (it's a database query for the timestamp):

```
public function getCounter ($task_id, $user_id) {
    $output = false;
    if($this->User->UserLog->hasAny(array(  
        'user_id' => $user_id,
        'task_id' => $task_id,
        'end_time' => null,
    ))) {
        $output = $this->User->UserLog->field('start_time', array(
            'user_id' => $user_id,
            'task_id' => $task_id,
            'end_time' => null,
        ));
        $output = strtotime($output);   
    }
    return $output;
}
```

and then just `$counter = $this->Task->getCounter ($task_id, $user_id);`

Comment: jQuery is client side and not server side. Are you sure is a php problem and not a client one?

Comment: You might be right about it being a client problem, I don't know where javascript gets current time from. Then again, how can I fix this and synchronize client time with database time (or read the offset and add it to the javascript start value)?

Comment: I added the js tag to your question, post your couter code if you want help

Comment: Now I see that you get the starting time from a PHP variable that is $counter. We're back to PHP, now. So you are saying that $counter differs from mysql NOW() time? Can you post even the php code?

Comment: No, it contains the database timestamp value. I'll add the php code too right away.

Comment: In database save dates in UTC timezone, and in JS parse dates as they were UTC, not local time.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the problem is that your jQuery plugin expect a JavaScript Date object while you are passing a Unix timestamp

try something like:

PHP

```
$counter = $counter*1000; //javascript expects milliseconds
```

JavaScript

```
$('#counter').countdown(
{
    since: new Date(<?php echo $counter?>), 
    format: 'HMS', 
    compact: true
 });
```

edit:
If your client is not in sync with your server your plugin let you synchronize the two.

Take a look at the timezone section in the countdown plugin.

You have to build a JS function that retrieve the actual server time using ajax an pass the function name to the plugin constructor.

```
function serverTime() { 
    var time = null; 
    $.ajax({url: 'http://myserver.com/serverTime.php', 
        async: false, dataType: 'text', 
        success: function(text) { 
            time = new Date(text); 
        }, error: function(http, message, exc) { 
            time = new Date(); 
    }}); 
    return time; 
}
```

Comment: That broke it even more, now I have a 300000+ hours of difference :). I forgot to mention, this works perfectly on my local machine (wamp server) where all time values are synced. The problem appears when I put it online. I think I just need to get the time difference between the client and my database, and offset the counter start value. That would solve my problem for any server migration later.

Answer (score 0):

Countdown js uses Client system date for displaying remaining time. So change in countdown js to check according to server current time. Do it by hard code.

I have done like below and works for me.

```
    // serverdate_js is server current time for javascript in 'Y-m-d H:i:s' format
    var date_split = serverdate_js.split(' ');
    var date = date_split[0];
    var time = date_split[1];
    var date_arr = date.split('-');
    var time_arr = time.split(':');
    var curdate_time = new Date(date_arr[0]+" "+date_arr[1]+","+date_arr[2]+" "+time_arr[0]+":"+time_arr[1]+":"+time_arr[2]);

  var $this = $(this),
      values = {},
      lasting = {},
      interval = $this.data('countdownInterval'),
      currentDate = curdate_time,
      secondsLeft = Math.floor((toDate.valueOf() - currentDate.valueOf()) / 1000);
```

Comment: Where do you set this?